# No CSS or JS on IIS 7

Tags: python, html, css, django, iis

I am running a Django (1.8) application on IIS 7 (via FastCGI), but there is no css being rendered.  I gave permission to IIS_IUSRS for the static content.  I have tried the following:

1. Enabled Static Content for IIS in Windows Features
2. Created a virtual directory pointing to my static folder
3. Re-added the .css in MIME Types
4. Added module mapping for .css

None of these have worked so far.  Everything in the application works except that there is no styling from the css.  When I run the application in chrome i get the following errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/autocomplete_light/style.css".
localhost/:76 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/css/jquery-ui.css".
localhost/:87 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css".
localhost/:90 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css".
localhost/:93 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/dist/css/timeline.css".
localhost/:96 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css".
localhost/:99 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css".
localhost/:102 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/w2ui-1.4.3/w2ui-1.4.3.min.css".
```

Comment: Can you try reinstall IIS or restart as it may be required after the permission changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by giving permission to the `IUSR` account.  Both `IIS_IUSRS` and `IUSR` must have permission.  To add the `IUSR` go to your apps folder -> Right Click -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add -> And add the `IUSR` account.  The account should have permission to Read & Execute, List Folder contents, and Read.

After adding this account the static content (CSS and JS) started to work.